# Several azure virtual machines with the same public ip address

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine

What are the resources I need to have several azure virtual machines (with their correspondant private ips) behind the same public ip? Load balancer, public ip address resource (but associated with what)...?
Do I need to associate a public ip address to the same network interface (seems not to be possible) or virtual network, having those network interface or virtual network associated to several virtual machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Azure load balancer, there are two SKUs: basic and standard. Each of SKU has internal or public type. You can use public load balancer of any SKU, then add the azure virtual machines, scale sets or availability sets as the backend pool. The public IP address of load balancer is an independent resource which is not associated with any other network interfaces. Every VM behind the load balancer have its private IP address or you can add its individual public IP address.

You can get more details about [Azure load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview).

Comment: Ok.
Now I have one load balancer, which frontend ip is a public ip resource created for that, and three vms as the backend pool.
My itention is to setup a nifi cluster in those vms. But now I need to ssh through my public ip, and then, ssh to the vms in order to complete the setup.
Public IP Addres azure resource doesn't give me the possibility of accessing via ssh.
I'm missing something else here.

Comment: You could create [a load balancer rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/quickstart-load-balancer-standard-public-portal#create-a-load-balancer-rule) for listening ssh port 22, also NSG must allow port 22 if you have NSG associated with that VMs subnet.

Comment: I'll do so. Thanks a lot Nancy